# Can we define this integral as $\int_a^bfd\gamma=\lim_{||P||\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^m f(\tau_k)[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 60 Conway proves a theorem and makes a definition:

[image]

Maybe I'm worrying to much but is there a problem to define

$$\int_a^bfd\gamma=\lim_{||P||\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^m f(\tau_k)[\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})]$$

For whatever choice of points $\tau_k,\ t_{k-1}\le \tau_k\le t_k$?

If there isn't any problem I didn't understand why he didn't define this integral as this limit after prove the theorem 1.4. I think the limit definition is simpler to prove some theorems such as the linearity of the integral (the proof is direct since the limit is linear as well) avoiding to worry about $\epsilon, \delta$ manipulations.

Comment: The $\epsilon-\delta$ formalism is how you define the limit as $\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @TrialAndError yes, exactly! that's why I've been asking myself why he didn't use the limit definition after the theorem.

Comment: I see. So you are saying that he never writes the unique number $I$ as $\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum\cdots$? That does seem a little odd.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral
and the $\epsilon$ bounded variation property should let us know that a $\epsilon$ discretisation of the integral will lead to a $L \epsilon$ approximation of $I$ (where $L$ is the length of the path)